# Tensorboard Visual Debugger UnimplementedError object not iterable

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, tensorboard

My model is able to run fine until I try and use the visual debugger.
When I remove tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession the model runs fine.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "...", line 337, in 
>       feed_dict={X: X_mb, z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
>   TypeError: 'UnimplementedError' object is not iterable

If more context is needed for my code I will accordingly edit the following.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
sess = tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(sess, "MYPORT")
...
...
_, D_loss_curr, _ = sess.run(
            [D_solver, D_loss, clip_D],
                feed_dict={X: X_mb, z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem on windows, see open issue:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17933

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [Linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)), we prefer answer that provide at least a solid summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information. [More info on link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).